# How to get PhantomJS to render installed fonts?

Tags: fonts, centos, phantomjs

I'm using Phantom JS to render PDFs from HTML source. The text will contain many different scripts. Currently I have an issue with Hebrew.

Generally when I see black squares instead of glyphs I look for the font package using `yum list | grep fonts` and install what I find, for example:

```
yum install fonts-hebrew fonts-arabic
```

This has worked for some scripts but not others. After installing fonts-arabic I can see those glyphs in the PDF, but Hebrew is blank. Not black squares as with missing fonts, but just blank.

The HTML doesn't reference any of the particular fonts installed by these packages, it just uses CSS to render as Arial and fall back to sans-serif. All the glyphs render fine in my local browser, but how can I get the PhantomJS renderer to pick up the hebrew fonts?

Additional info: I am on CentOS 5.5, running PhantomJS 1.9

Comment: Is this with Phantom running locally, too?

Comment: My local is a Mac and seems to work very differently with Phantom. It actually renders the whole PDF as an image.

Answer (score 1):

## Steps I followed to solve this

1.Checked if Arabic Support is available:

```
yum grouplist
```

2.Then if available install arabic support:

```
yum groupinstall 'Arabic Support'.
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: Hej, I have a question, i have a system where i cannot use yum.
Can you list the installed packages, so i can install them manually?